# Mismatched types when trying to parse JSON from curl with serde_json

Tags: rust, serde-json

I've got JSON output from an API for open WIFI which I want to put into a database. The data is in [this form](https://map.freifunk-rhein-neckar.de/data/nodes.json).

I already got the information via `curl`:

```
let mut easy = Easy::new();
easy.url("https://map.freifunk-rhein-neckar.de/data/nodes.json")
    .unwrap();
easy.write_function(|data| Ok(stdout().write(data).unwrap()))
    .unwrap();
easy.perform().unwrap();

let mut json = easy.response_code().unwrap();
```

I tried to use serde_json:

```
extern crate curl;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use curl::easy::Easy;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde_json::Error;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Freifunk {
    timestamp: u32,
    version: i8,
    nodes: u32,
}

fn json_to_rust() -> Result<(), Error> {
    //Json von Homepage "Auslesen/Downloaden"
    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://map.freifunk-rhein-neckar.de/data/nodes.json")
        .unwrap();
    easy.write_function(|data| Ok(stdout().write(data).unwrap()))
        .unwrap();
    easy.perform().unwrap();

    let mut json = easy.response_code().unwrap();

    let to_string: Freifunk = serde_json::from_value(json)?;
}

fn main() {}
```

I always get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:54
   |
29 |     let to_string: Freifunk = serde_json::from_value(json)?;
   |                                                      ^^^^ expected enum `serde_json::Value`, found u32
   |
   = note: expected type `serde_json::Value`
              found type `u32`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:40
   |
18 |   fn json_to_rust() -> Result<(), Error> {
   |  ________________________________________^
19 | |     //Json von Homepage "Auslesen/Downloaden"
20 | |     let mut easy = Easy::new();
21 | |     easy.url("https://map.freifunk-rhein-neckar.de/data/nodes.json")
...  |
29 | |     let to_string: Freifunk = serde_json::from_value(json)?;
30 | | }
   | |_^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<(), serde_json::Error>`
              found type `()`
```

Could you give me an example of how to process the data to get it into a database?

Answer (score 1):

> I already got the information via curl:

No, you didn't. You downloaded it but then wrote it to standard out:

```
easy.write_function(|data| Ok(stdout().write(data).unwrap()))
```

What you have called `json` is the [HTTP response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). This is a value of type `u32`:

```
let mut json = easy.response_code().unwrap();
```

Getting the data into a vector is [described in the curl documentation](https://docs.rs/curl/0.4.8/curl/easy/struct.Easy.html). The compiler *told you* you had incorrect types; you need to read and understand it, then figure out why the types are wrong:

```
   = note: expected type `serde_json::Value`
              found type `u32`
```

Additionally, you can't use `from_value` because you don't have a `serde_json::Value` to read from.

Your second error is because you've declared that your function returns a `Result`, but you don't return such at the end of your function. You just... stop, which returns a `()`

```
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<(), serde_json::Error>`
              found type `()`
```

---

```
extern crate curl;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use curl::easy::Easy;
use serde_json::Error;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Freifunk {
    timestamp: u32,
    version: i8,
    nodes: u32,
}

fn json_to_rust() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut json = Vec::new();

    let mut easy = Easy::new();
    easy.url("https://map.freifunk-rhein-neckar.de/data/nodes.json")
        .unwrap();
    {
        let mut transfer = easy.transfer();
        transfer
            .write_function(|data| {
                json.extend_from_slice(data);
                Ok(data.len())
            })
            .unwrap();
        transfer.perform().unwrap();
    }

    assert_eq!(200, easy.response_code().unwrap());

    let freifunk: Freifunk = serde_json::from_slice(&json)?;

    println!("{:?}", freifunk);

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {}
```